# jquery .html does not work with script

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

This code is not working on IE8 at all. FF3 is executing but the page is blank and seems loading not ending.

My code is:

```
$("#leaderBoard").html("<script2 language=\"javascript2\"> document.write('<scr'+'ipt language=\"javascript21.1\">alert(1)</scri'+'pt>'); </script2>".replace(/script2/gi, "script"));
```

I want to let page load ad on ready.

Comment: are you trying to load a script when dom is ready?

Comment: Use of the `language` attribute is depricated.  Use type="text/javascript" instead.  Also, prefer DOM over document.write.  Also...  use jQuery's script loader, or eval.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me in FF3 and IE7:

```
$("#leaderBoard").html('<sc'+'ript language="javascript1.1">alert(1);</sc'+'ript>');
```

When you use document.write after the page has loaded, it replaces the entire document (http://javascript.about.com/library/blwrite.htm). You essentially replaced your page content with a script tag, causing it to appear blank.

Answer (score 3):

When you actually have jQuery already, why all the obfuscating hassle?

Simply load the ad HTML into the leaderBoard object, and you're done.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("#leaderBoard").load("/ad_generator.php");
});
```

Where `ad_generator.php` would produce an HTML fragment based on some randomization scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try using jQuery's $.getScript(); function?

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getScript

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```
//////////////////function in page's script section

function aFunction (x) {

    ////script you want to execute

    alert(x);

}

//////////////////////in page's body

var d = $("<div />");
d.ready(function(){aFunction("x");});
```

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping your code in

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 // your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.write()
```

does not work with the window.onload event

try this code

```
 $('.myDiv').html('<script src="path\/to-add\/provider"><\/script>');
```

somewhere near the end of your document
*Notice* that you have to escape the '/' charecter